# What does "with respect to the exclusion of a set" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, ideals

I'm not good at English, but I'm studying math in English. Can anyone explain to me what is this sentence means?

> Let $Q$ be an ideal maximal with respect to the exclusion of $T$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are studying multiplicative sets, it is probably in connection with this lemma:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring,  $T$ is a multiplicative subset$^\ast$ and $I$ is an ideal maximal with respect to exclusion of $T$, then $I$ is a prime ideal.

It means that $I$ has the property that if $J$ is another ideal properly containing $I$, then $J\cap T\neq \emptyset$.

---

$^\ast$ the definition ought to include the clause that $0\notin T\neq\emptyset$, of course

Comment: I'm indeed trying to solve that lemma. Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Alephnull's intepretation, maybe it's a mistake and the sentence should have been

> let $Q$ be a maximal ideal in $T$ with respect to inclusion.

If the sentence has been written by a non-native English speaker, this intepretation seems reasonable.

Comment: I'm sure that it's exclusion, not inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be express as following:

Consider the set $\mathbb{E}= \{ J ~\text{proper ideal of }R / J \cap {T} =\varnothing \}$, where $T$ is a multiplicative set.

> An ideal in $\mathbb{E}$ is said to respect to the exclusion of $T$.

So the phrase **"Let Q be a maximal  ideal with respect to the exclusion of T"**, means simply that $Q$ is maximal in  $\mathbb{E}$

[You can see this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328581/meaning-of-with-respect-to-the-exclusion-of-set)

Answer (score -1):

It is an ideal that is the largest without containing any elements of T. That is to say all other ideals that do not contain elements of T are subsets of Q.

Comment: Possibly, it could also mean that it is maximal within its own chain of ideals not containing elements of T, but other maximal ideals are permitted if they are incommensurable with  Q: that is neither is a subset of the either. This is similar to a maximal ideal.

Comment: I think you've overstated what you meant in this solution. For example, all maximal ideals of a commutative ring maximally exclude $\{1\}$, but they don't mutually contain each other. It's the difference between "a maximal element" and "the maximum element" that I'm trying to get at. I think you meant to say that instead.

Comment: @rschwieb yeah i put it in the comments. I thought that too.